# Restrict enum values by user role

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an enum of actions. The actions are partitioned by two user roles. The users make requests to an app via Web API. How can I restrict the values accepted by the Web API action based on user role?

At the moment I have two roles and I'm using two enums and two Web API methods. When a value is passed to a database repository it's cast to an integer. This isn't ideal - I'd prefer to use an amalgamation of the enums in the repository interface.

So...

Admins can request that actions from Enum1 are performed and non-admins can do likewise for the actions in Enum2. But the repository method that performs the work can work with integer values from both because authorisation has been handled.

Enum inheritance would fix this if enums were inheritable.

```
enum EnumAdmin { Action1 = 1, Action2 = 2 }
enum EnumNotAdmin { Action3 = 3, Action4 = 4 }

void DoAction(int action);

[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public IActionResult AdminMethod(EnumAdmin param)
{
   repos.DoAction((int) param);
}

[Authorize(Roles = "NotAdmin")]
public IActionResult AdminMethod(EnumNotAdmin param)
{
   repos.DoAction((int) param);
}
```

**EDIT:** Well, nothing to see here as my scheme doesn't work anyway.

[Able to assign an invalid Enum value via reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276575/able-to-assign-an-invalid-enum-value-via-reflection)

Comment: As in: "You are not allowed to send value X, choose Y or Z instead"?

Comment: Possibly a more obtuse response will be sent to the user, but yes, admins can do X and non-admins can do Y and there's no overlap.

Comment: I feel like you are describing an upside down approach to doing this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: In what way is it upside down?

Comment: @AustinTFrench I could create a fancy authorisation mechanism that checks the values are allowed for the user's role but I was hoping for something more succinct.

Comment: I don't see why, when you could decorate the controller action with: `[Authorize(Roles=Roles.Administrator.ToString()]` or similar. (or a constant, or any number of things very similar...

Comment: @IanWarburton I'll add, I might be missing in your question too...

Comment: @AustinTFrench I'm already doing that. I ought to flesh out the question with some code. Two Web API methods. One for admins. One for non-admins. One method takes a parameter of type admin enum. The other method has a parameter of type non-admin enum. But the repository method further down the stack can handle any value from either enum. The only reason I have two enums instead of one is to restrict the values that each role can submit.

Comment: What is the limation for your current design by converting enum to int?

Comment: @TaoZhou It means having to use a cast every time the method is called.

Comment: After all that, my scheme doesn't work anyway. Model binding binds an illegal value to an enum without complaining! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276575/able-to-assign-an-invalid-enum-value-via-reflection

Answer (score 0):

You have updated the question for problem definition. I think you can use the flyweight design pattern for the problem. Not very good but I sampled below. I used class for the role. Because the enum type is sealed.

```
   public class User
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class RoleBase
    {

    }

    public class RoleAdmin: RoleBase
    {
     public bool Action1 { get; set; }
     public bool Action2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class RoleNotAdmin: RoleBase
    {
        public bool Action3 { get; set; }
        public bool Action4 { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IPermission
    {
        bool IsAuthorization(RoleBase role, User user);
    }

    public class PermissionAdmin : IPermission
    {
        public bool IsAuthorization(RoleBase roleBase, User user)
        {
            var roleAdmin = roleBase as RoleAdmin;

            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question.